# MS Access 2021 : using the rowsource property on a form and executing a stored procedure from SQL Server - how? What am I missing?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures

I thought it would be as easy as this...

[image]

but nothing ever gets returned when drop down arrow is selected (it is a combo list box).

I have a connection string, and all other vba query calls function correctly.

This is the first time I am trying to code this directly to the form via a stored procedure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: RowSource set to table or query named "Exec dbo.Rev_SelectCombo"? That seems odd. What function?

Comment: dbo.Rev_SelectCombo is a stored procedure on the sql server.

Comment: I am just guessing but I doubt can have stored procedure as RowSource. A pass-through query works. Review https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/a079a6d7-2eae-45b5-adfd-1e9e2222530f/populating-a-combo-box-using-a-stored-procedure-with-parameters?forum=accessdev#:~:text=Because%20this%20is%20a%20store%20procedure%2C%20best%20to,the%20pass%20though%20query%2C%20and%20use%20this%20code%3A

Comment: you have to save Exec dbo.Rev_SelectCombo in a pass through query and set row source to it